# Creating unknown Multiple columns - each has the same XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I am creating a new Xaml with new ViewModel.
I would like to create new xaml that holds number of this view model.
each view model should show a xaml (same xaml) and I would like it to be one next to each other (like columns). (something like stackPanel)

what is the best way to do this?

something like this pic:[image: number of columns can be change dynamically]

thank you

Comment: nice pic, but the question is unclear. please give an example of your view models. may be an `ItemsControl` is the best solution in your case, if viewmodels are stored in a collection

Comment: Lets say I have PersonViewModel. and I I want each column to be a person.. But.. I dont know how many persons I have.I hope this is more clear. (I have a XAML that represant one person lets say PersonView - so if I have 4 personsVIewmodels I would like to see 4 culomns)

Answer (score 0):

what I was searching for was something like:

```
   <ItemsControl Name="icTodoList" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonsList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <tempProject:PersonView Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```